# activeadmin outputting the value from a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have the following code in an AA panel -> attribute_table_for ...

```
row 'ambassadors2' do
  event.ambassadors.each do |user|
    if can? :read, user
      a(user.name, href: admin_user_path(user))
    else
      span(user.name)
    end
  end
end
```

The strange thing is that it ouptuts the `user.name` at the end like this (in orange):

[image]

But the AA code doesn't reflect this. What is going on?

Comment: The `row` method may be trying to render the content inside the block. When you call `each` and nothing else, the return result will be the collection itself (e.g. `[Devon Toy, Myles Champlin, ...]`) which gets rendered as an awkwardly formatted string inside the AA view.

Comment: I think something like that is going on - it's my first time using activeadmin.  What would be the canonical way to fix it?. would adding an empty string at the end of the block do it?

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion. Give it a shot

Comment: ok - I will at work tomorrow - ain't working on this at home :)

Comment: I hear ya. All about work/life balance. What I would try is returning a string, perhaps by first mapping and then joining. `event.ambassadors.map { |user| ... }.join.html_safe`